# ¿Cómo agregar imágenes a cada ítem de un ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, listview

Tengo una aplicacion que en un su NavigationDrawer tiene un ExpandableListView au vez este tiene cuatro grupos padre, dentro de gada uno hay un grupo hijo el cual posterior mente cargaran mediante ArrayLists. Los childGroup incluyen una Imagen y un texto pero la imagen se repite en todas las filas y está asociado al Layout list_subcategoria.xml, en el adaptador en el método **getChildView** se carga el texto pero no hace referencia a la imagen en el layout, como podría modificarlo para que cargue diferentes imagenes desde el MainActivity en el método **initData()**, por ejemplo: itemMenus1.add("Home",R.drawable.img1);
    itemMenus1.add("Biblioteca",R.drawable.img2);  **[PROYECTO](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/NavigationExpandableListView)** en GitHub.

list_subcategoria.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#142a46">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_scate_icon"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="SubCategoria" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adaptador:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;
int[] imagen;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {

    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return listDataHeader.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);// i= Group item, i1 = childItem
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String headerTittle = (String)getGroup(i);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_categoria,null);
    }
    TextView item_cate_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_cate_name);
    item_cate_name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item_cate_name.setText(headerTittle);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
    final int childImg =  (int)getChild(i,i1);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria,null);
    }
    TextView item_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
    item_name.setText(childText);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return false;
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//ExpandableListView
private ExpandableListView listView;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    //ListView
    listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.ex_lits_menu);
    initData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,listHash);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}

//Cargue ListView
private void initData() {

    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listHash = new HashMap<>();

    listDataHeader.add("Portal");
    listDataHeader.add("Plataformas");
    listDataHeader.add("Redes Sociales");
    listDataHeader.add("Entretenimiento");

    List<String> itemMenus1 = new ArrayList<>();
    itemMenus1.add("Home");
    itemMenus1.add("Biblioteca");
    itemMenus1.add("EduVirtual");
    itemMenus1.add("Directorio");
    itemMenus1.add("Preguntas");

    List<String> itemMenus2 = new ArrayList<>();
    itemMenus2.add("Siga");
    itemMenus2.add("Siga");
    itemMenus2.add("Apoyo a la Presencialidad");
    itemMenus2.add("Virtualidad");

    List<String> itemMenus3 = new ArrayList<>();
    itemMenus3.add("Youtube");
    itemMenus3.add("Twitter");
    itemMenus3.add("Facebook");
    itemMenus3.add("Flicker");
    itemMenus3.add("Google +");
    itemMenus3.add("Instagram");
    itemMenus3.add("LinkedIn");

    List<String> itemMenus4 = new ArrayList<>();
    itemMenus4.add("Tour 360");
    itemMenus4.add("Juegos");

    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),itemMenus1);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(1),itemMenus2);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(2),itemMenus3);
    listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(3),itemMenus4);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: de donde deseas obtener las imágenes? donde están definidas por cada elemento? esto agregalo a tu pregunta

Comment: Vale, estoy editando la pregunta.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya la edité, es que me estoy cambiando a ListView en mi proyecto pues con RecyclerView tuve problemas que no se pudieron solucionar. XD

Comment: dentro de getChildView() puedes agregar la imagen correspondiente, similar a como lo realizas con el texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisamente en `list_subcategoria.xml` que inflas en getChildView() de tu adapter puedes agregar la imagen, obten la referencia del ImageView y agrega una imagen.

En este ejemplo puedes usar `Picasso` para cargar tus imágenes, agregando la siguiente dependencia en tu `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

de esta forma cargarías la imagen definida en la variable childImg  de cada elemento:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
    final int childImg =  (int)getChild(i,i1);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria,null);
    }
    TextView item_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
    item_name.setText(childText);
     
    /*****************************/

    ImageView item_icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scate_icon);
   Picasso.with(context).load(childImg).into(item_icon);

    /*****************************/
    return view;
}
```

---

#### Actualización:

Para agregar propiedades de cada elemento hijo dentro de cada grupo en un `ExpandableListView` es mucho más sencillo el uso de un objeto el cual tenga las propiedades que deseas para cada elemento, por ejemplo su descripción y la imagen, ejemplo:

```
public class ElementoMenu {

    private String titulo;
    private int imagenResource;

    public int getImagenResource() {
        return imagenResource;
    }

    public void setImagenResource(int imagenResource) {
        this.imagenResource = imagenResource;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

}
```

de esta forma puedes crear los elementos de cada grupo :

```
   List<ElementoMenu> itemMenus1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ElementoMenu elemento = new ElementoMenu("Home", R.drawable.img1);
    itemMenus1.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Biblioteca", R.drawable.img2);
    itemMenus1.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("EduVirtual", R.drawable.img3);
    itemMenus1.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Directorio", R.drawable.img4);
    itemMenus1.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Preguntas", R.drawable.img1);
    itemMenus1.add(elemento);

    List<ElementoMenu> itemMenus2 = new ArrayList<>();
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Siga", R.drawable.img1);
    itemMenus2.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Apoyo a la Presencialidad", R.drawable.img2);
    itemMenus2.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Virtualidad", R.drawable.img3);
    itemMenus2.add(elemento);

    List<ElementoMenu> itemMenus3 = new ArrayList<>();
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Youtube", R.drawable.img1);
    itemMenus3.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Twitter", R.drawable.img2);
    itemMenus3.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Facebook", R.drawable.img3);
    itemMenus3.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Flicker", R.drawable.img4);
    itemMenus3.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Google +", R.drawable.img1);
    itemMenus3.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Instagram", R.drawable.img2);
    itemMenus3.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("LinkedIn", R.drawable.img3);
    itemMenus3.add(elemento);

    List<ElementoMenu> itemMenus4 = new ArrayList<>();
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Tour 360", R.drawable.img1);
    itemMenus4.add(elemento);
    elemento = new ElementoMenu("Juegos", R.drawable.img2);
    itemMenus4.add(elemento);
```

y en lugar de enviar a tu adapter un `List<String>> listHashMap` enviarias a tu `Adapter` un `List<ElementoMenu>> listHashMap`.

Para obtener las propiedades entro de los objetos realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
  @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
         //Obtiene titulo.
        final String childText = listElementosMenu.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1).getTitulo();
        //Obtiene Imagen.
        final int childImg =  listElementosMenu.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1).getImagenResource();
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria,null);
        }
        TextView item_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
        item_name.setText(childText);
        ImageView item_icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scate_icon);
        item_icon.setImageResource(childImg);
        return view;
    }
```

Este sería el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo he cambiado pero en el MainActivity  no recibe la ruta de las imagenes. aquí por ejemplo itemMenus1.add("Home"); no acepta este cambio itemMenus1.add("Home",R.drawable.img1); pide cambio "to (java.lang.String, int)"

Comment: Será que esto no es posible, he buscado y no he encontrado un tutorial que enseñe a hacerlo, y con ExpandableRecyclerview se logró pero hay problema con los eventos. :´(

Comment: @Alfredo es posible, en lugar de un HashMap realizar un objeto, solo indicame cuales son los url de las imagenes o los id de recursos imagen que deseas utlizar.

Comment: si las imagenes estan en la carpeta drawable con nombre img1, img2, img3, img4, img5; tambien si me puedes proporcionar una url que me enseñe a crear un ExpandableListView paso a paso, este me pareció muy entendible en la estructura aunque hay componentes que no entiendo como HashMap. en este ejercicio está unicamente el ExpandableListView no hay muchos mas archivos pues apenas inicio con él. **[PROYECTO](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/NavigationExpandableListView)**

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67710/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-como-agregar-imagenes-a-cada-item-de-un-expand).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67711/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-alfredo).